# CoreAnimation - Very low FPS when animating a layer over a lot of other layers - Test Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-animation

I've got a CAReplicatorLayer with a lot of replications of a small CAShapeLayer (a circle).

Then I animate another CAShapeLayer (a square). It's constantly moving left and right.

The CoreAnimation FPS which the profiler shows are very low (around 20-30) and you can see how much it lags on the device (iPad 3, iOS 8.1).

I know that I could potentially increase the performance a little by rasterizing parts of the scene, but I'm looking for another appraoch here. How can I improve the performance of this demo project without rasterizing?  (In my main project there's so many layers that I can't use rasterization as it will take up too much memory)

Here's the project:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40859730/CoreAnimationPerformanceTest.zip

EDIT: I forgot to say that I'm CPU bound, the GPU usage is very very low, while the CARenderServer usage goes up to 100-120%

Comment: Run it through Instruments. Are you CPU bound or GPU bound? What is taking up the most CPU? What step in the GPU is taking up the most time? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: It's CPU bound, the CARenderServer is using up to 120% of CPU according to Instruments / Xcode profiler.